# Is it possible to keep as electron at rest, or with momentum precisely zero?

Tags: special-relativity, electric-fields, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Is it possible to make an free electron come to rest in a vacuum chamber using electric fields, or to make it's momentum precisely to zero? If that can happen don't you think it will be a violation of uncertainty relation and that would also imply that the electrostatic field formula would become true and that will imply an action at a distance?
$\vec{E}=\dfrac{kq}{r^2}\widehat{r}$

Comment: Uncertainty relation is an equation involving the uncertainties on, in this case, position and momentum: why would that be violated?

Comment: You _could_, but you'd have no idea where in the Universe it were.

Answer (score 1):

if momentum is precisely zero, then deBroglie wavelength is infinite - it cannot be localized.